# Delaying a Nagios/Icinga check

Tags: monitoring, nagios, system-monitoring, icinga

When monitoring the healthy of a server, some faults or warnings are immediately urgent but others only matter if they persist. I'm thinking of things like:

- Some software needs to be updated
- Time offset differs from NTP

If unaddressed these could become real problems, but there are already background services in place to take care of them - unattended upgrades, an NTP client service etc. There's always a short delay between the problem arising and these background processes kicking in to address them, and our monitor is sending out a series of emails in that gap - then again a minute later when the issue is fixed. I generally wake up to a large pile of "PROBLEM" emails, each with a corresponding "RESOLUTION" emails sent a minute later. The danger is that in dismissing a hundred irrelevant warnings, I could miss the one that's real.

So is there any way of instructing Icinga or Nagios to only report an issue if it's continued for more than a certain time, say 5 minutes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SvW is not wrong in what (s)he writes, but you should also investigate the variable `max_check_attempts`, which defines how many checks a service has to fail before going HARD error and notifying.

For some of my hair-trigger services, I have

```
max_check_attempts              2
check_interval                  2
retry_interval                  1
```

which means that NAGIOS will check more often than usual, and once it notices something's down, it'll wait 1 minute, check once more, then notify.  For other services, where I don't care until it's been down a while, I have

```
max_check_attempts              12
check_interval                  5
retry_interval                  5
```

which means that once NAGIOS notices something's down, it'll carry on checking every 5 minutes as usual, and not tell me until it's been down for an hour.

It is **definitely** worth tuning your NAGIOS until it tells you about the things you care about, at the time you care about them, and nothing else; a monitoring system that emits a cloud of false positives (ie, sends you loads of notifications you don't really care about) is nearly as useless as one that has false negatives (ie, fails to notice a real problem).

Comment: Regarding your last sentence: Yes, exactly. Getting Nagios to be useful is complicated and not done in one session, you have to adapt it to your environment in every aspect and that takes time.

Comment: I completely agree; most of my work with it is tuning, not installation.  I think this is true of **all** monitoring systems: for them to be useful, substantial work will be required over and above just making them run.

Answer (score 3):

You can define detailed configurations to tell Nagios every detail about the check for a service.

Look up the `check_interval` and `retry_interval` config options, and while you are at it, learn about time periods in general.